# External program call through java

Tags: java, linux, ns2

I want to run NS2(which is an external program in linux) commands through java, using ProcessBuilder
when I get the ns command not found error

```
/home/maria/Documents/test.sh: line 4: ns: command not found
Execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:153)
at test.opencmd.runScript(opencmd.java:18)
at test.opencmd.main(opencmd.java:30)
```

my java code is

```
package test;
import java.io.*;
public class test2 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
String s = null;
try {
// run the Unix "};
    //System.out.print(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "ns /home/maria/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen && cbrgen.tcl -type cbr -nn 10 -seed 1 -mc 5 -rate 5.0");
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
// read the output from the command
System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(s);
}
// read any errors from the attempted command
System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(s);
}
System.exit(0);
}
catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
e.printStackTrace();
System.exit(-1);
}
}
}
```

I guess i am not making a right program call.

Comment: Can you try putting the full path to the ns command when starting it?

Comment: please try same command in linux terminal. and check whether it will work

Comment: it works in terminal. But gives error in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the terminal/session which jvm executes your command doesn't know where/what is 'ns' [i.e: your executable library]

Try executing by giving the full path to your library, like

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "/fullpath/ns /home/maria/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-....
```

Comment: I guess this must be the solution.

Comment: the problem is now syntax. how do i pass path to library and command to run in .exec() funtion ?

Answer (score 1):

if `NS` is a java program then use `java ns` as below.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "java ns /home/maria/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen && cbrgen.tcl -type cbr -nn 10 -seed 1 -mc 5 -rate 5.0");
```

Comment: thanx. NS is not a java program

Answer (score 1):

Java is unable to find 'ns'. To tell that to Java program you have to mention full path as below:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/maria/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest/setdest -v 2 -n 50 -p 2.0 -s 10.0 -t 200 -x 500 -y 500 -m 2 -M 15");
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/maria/ns-allinone-2.35/bin/ns /home/maria/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/cbrgen.tcl -type cbr -nn 10 -seed 1 -mc 5 -rate 5.0");
```